# error in collection select, unable to use default value in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following code to get the default value

```
<%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, {:selected => session["location"]},:formatted_display, { prompt: true }, :required => true,  :class => 'chosen-select order_form' %>
```

I am getting the following error when I try the above:

```
wrong number of arguments (7 for 4..6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
<%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name,{ :prompt => true , :selected => session["location"]},  :class => 'chosen-select order_form'%>
```

Comment: It works with this edit 

`<%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true , :selected => session["location"]},  :class => 'chosen-select order_form'%>`